# Closest English term for Spanish "merienda"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation, spanish

The Spanish word *merienda* is often included in lists of untranslatable words. It originally meant the meal you had around noon between breakfast and dinner, as that meal used to be small compared with the other two. In some parts it is still used with that sense but since the 17th century it is almost always used for the small meal you have between lunch and dinner.

In Spain you usually have lunch around 2:00 PM and dinner around 9:00 PM, so at around 5:30 you need a small meal if you do not want to starve. That small meal is our *merienda*.

I would like to know if there are or there have been words in English to refer to a similar small meal you have between the main meals. I have looked up the word even in old dictionaries, but I think the translations refer to the old meaning of the word:

- The Spanish-English dictionary by Richard Percyvall from 1591 translates the word as *noonemeate* (currently *[noonmeat](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/noonmeat)*), but that seems to be a synonym for *lunch*.
- The Spanish-Latin-English dictionary by Iohannis Minshaei from 1617 translates the word as *a Bever*. That word is not present in the Oxford dictionary but seems to be related to *beverage*. Etymonline says its meaning [could be](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bevy) "a drinking bout".
- The closest word I can think of is US English *[snack](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/snack)*: "a small amount of food eaten between meals" or "a light meal that is eaten in a hurry or in a casual manner".

So among every word the English language has produced everywhere and at every time, old and new, known or unknown, what would be the closest one to Spanish *merienda*?

Comment: As merienda no longer has a definitive meaning, it might be easily translated into English with an English term with an indefinite meaning; tea. Tea is often a small meal taken in the afternoon.

Comment: @J.Taylor indeed! "A light afternoon meal consisting typically of tea to drink, sandwiches, and cakes." You could add that as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a proper answer here. Instead of translating, one should use the local term.  In my mind, explaining merienda is better than trying to translate it.

Comment: as a side note, the term is present also in Italian as *merenda* but it has survived mainly to refer to mid-morning snack break that children have at primary schools.

Comment: @user240918 in Spanish (at least in the area where I live) that mid-morning snack the children have is known as "merendilla" (a small _merienda_).

Comment: @Charlie - yes, it is sometimes called  *merendina* also in Italian.

Comment: Exist also in Romanian https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/merinde Borowed to Czech as a meeting food, drinks, dancing or other leasure and to Moravian dialects in the Romanian meaning https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/merenda

Comment: How does the 'merienda' work? Is it over all Spanish speaking countries? If not what areas? Is it for most people or only working people? Do you have it right away when you get home after work? Is it an upper/middle/lower class thing, or just for kids or just for people who work in an office or what? What kinds of things does one eat: cooked, prepared, tapas from a bar? Do you eat it alone or as a group? etc etc etc.

Comment: Note that the answer may well be 'merienda, kind of like high tea, or an early evening snack' just like the translation of 'siesta' might be 'siesta, kind of like a rest period or nap after lunch before going back to work'. That is, there may not be any word at all because it is so peculiar to non-anglophone practices/culture.

Comment: Obviously you're confusing dinner with 4th meal.

Comment: I don’t know if the *word* untranslatable so much as the *culture* and tradition embedded in that word.

Comment: I've always heard it called "lupper".

Comment: In synagogues around the world, we call it *Kiddush*, a pre-meal appetizer after services. Then we go home and eat a large midday meal. We might ask a guest to stop in "for kiddush," then they go off to their own meal and we begin ours. Kiddush usually offers both savory and sweet treats.

Answer (score 14):

I think your question contains its answer: ***snack*** is both AE [and BE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snack), and the first example sentence reported by the Oxford Dictionary is

> not many people make it through to the evening meal without a snack

which seems to reflect your definition quite perfectly: "at around 5:30 you need a small meal if you do not want to starve"

Comment: Maybe 'late afternoon snack'

Comment: I definitely vote for "snack" understanding it as just about anything edible that one consumes between formal meals, a very informal "chewing session". The purpose of a "merienda" is to calm down your hunger while you wait for your next proper meal. Furthermore, a merienda can happen at any time of the day -morning or afternoon- as long as it is taken before a formal meal. In most Spanish-speaking countries it is understood in this fashion. Maybe in more conservative cultures -Argentina or Chile?- the merienda may be more like the "British 5 o'clock Tea". I'm writing from Venezuela and that's

Answer (score 10):

I was surprised not to see ***tea*** in the answers until I saw it in the very first [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474808/closest-english-term-for-spanish-merienda#comment1146568_474808) by J. Taylor.

Also, consider ***high tea*** though not a single word.

MW:

> **[tea](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tea)** *noun*
>   **4a** : refreshments usually including tea with sandwiches, crackers, or cookies served in **late afternoon**

ODO:

> **[tea](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tea)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **3** [British] A light afternoon meal consisting typically of tea to drink, sandwiches, and cakes.
>
> ‘they were about to take afternoon tea’
>   [count noun] ‘picnic teas’
>
> **3.1** A cooked evening meal.
>
> ‘fish and chips for tea’
>
> [count noun] ‘it reminds me of Sunday teas when I was a very small
>   child’
>
> **[high tea](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/high_tea)**
>   *NOUN*   [British]
>   A meal eaten in the late afternoon or early evening, typically consisting of a cooked dish, bread and butter, and
>   tea.
>
> ‘you sat down and had high tea’

Comment: Yes. What is understood by "tea" in Britain can vary considerably. The "posh" take "tea" as you describe - "afternoon tea" between lunch and dinner - sandwiches, cakes and tea (drunk with little finger extended). However many working-class people call the main evening meal "tea". The genteel talk about "high tea", where it contains a cooked element. The whole subject is confused by the fact that in pre-Victorian Britain "dinner", the main meal of the day was taken around noon. This persisted among the working classes in the 20th century and remains the case with many people today (continued).

Comment: It was only when British people began to travel in Europe, that they noticed that the French and others took their main meal in the evening. Hence a word needed to be devised for the mid-day meal. "Luncheon", (or lunch) had previously been a snack taken mid-morning (and still is for some who call the mid-day meal "dinner"). The first OED entry for "luncheon" as a substantial meal in the early afternoon is in 1809.

Comment: Of course, in the US there is great confusion about these terms, and most Americans who say "high tea" actually mean "afternoon tea" by British definitions, because "high tea" sounds fancy.

Comment: Some bourgeois people in Britain refer to the main meal taken in the evening as "supper" - whilst for the working class "supper" is a snack you take just before bed. I think some Americans use "supper" in this bourgeois fashion.

Comment: @WS2 I can confirm that some Americans use "lunch" for a mid-morning snack, "dinner" for a midday meal, and "supper" for an evening meal.   Both "dinner" and "supper" were large meals, as those folks were farmers (and not the least bit bourgeois).  I think that usage is highly regional, however.

Comment: @CarlKevinson Yes. That is the old-fashioned working-class English nomenclature that I grew up with (also in a farming area), and which still persists with a lot of people. The exception would be supper. In our case we had breakfast, dinner (main meal abt 1.00pm, usually some form of meat - perhaps sausage, pudding for desert), tea (less-substantial e.g. fish & chips, or egg and baked beans on toast), and supper (snack e.g piece of cake and warm drink) before we went to bed. I'm talking here of the 1950s, and the message about economising on carbohydrates had not begun!

Comment: We Aussies have further confused the nomenclature. If one is invited for “tea”, one might be served “a cuppa and bikkies” or a hot evening meal, perhaps with dessert; this meal is otherwise known as “dinner”. A “high tea” would be fancy, pricey and usually partaken in big-city hotels, or in coffee shops or tea houses run by people with pretensions. The fare would include dainty morsels such as petit fours and ribbon sandwiches and be served with speciality teas or, grudgingly, with espresso for non-traditionalists. “Supper” is any food eaten after the evening meal; often a cuppa and bikkies.

Comment: @NMI That more or less follows the traditional British pattern, except the dainty session (in posh hotels, as you describe) would be "afternoon tea", and the hot meal in the evening "high tea". "Supper" - traditionally- is like yours. But bourgeois people often refer to the main evening meal as "supper", as they do in America. "Hight tea" as an expression is now quite dated. The only one that seems universally understood in the English-speaking world is "breakfast".

Comment: @WS2 Ah, yes. We all understand “breakfast”, except here in Oz it’s “brekkie” (or “brekky”). 

Comment: *Afternoon tea* may indeed seem to be the correct translation if one goes by the dictionary definitions, but I am afraid that this term is (especially outside Great Britain) too strongly associated with certain stereotypes about British culture and traditions to be suitable for something that people do in a very different culture.

Comment: You wouldn't have 'high tea' (in the British sense) if you were going to have your main meal at 9 p.m. as the Spanish do.

Answer (score 2):

Well, supper, for one. I believe it fits the context quite well.

Merriam Webster:

> supper noun
>
> sup·​per | \ˈsə-pər  \
>
> Definitions:
>
> 1a: the evening meal especially when dinner is taken at midday
>
> > b : a social affair featuring a supper
> >     especially: an evening social especially for raising funds
> >
> > > a church supper
>
> 2: the food served as a supper
>
> > 'eat your supper'
>
> 3: a light meal served late in the evening

Oxford:

> An evening meal, typically a light or informal one.
>
> > e.g.: ‘we had a delicious cold supper’

Comment: I've always considered supper to be a synonym for dinner. I don't think people in America typically eat dinner at midday.

Comment: I don't really consider 5:30 as "midday"

Comment: That's what I mean. We eat lunch at midday, the meal eaten between 5 and 7 is both supper and dinner.

Comment: The fact that *supper* is sometimes used for a **late** evening (i.e. after dinner) snack, could make it confusing to use it for an afternoon (i.e. before dinner) snack.

Comment: I would agree with @jsw29, supper is a small meal to be eaten late evening, a few hours *after* dinner... where diner was eaten at 5:30 pm. I often remember hearing "I fancy some kippers for dinner", mid-60s to mid-80s (and beyond), in Southern England (including London).

Answer (score 1):

After having lived in Spain for the last 14 year or so, I would classify it as rather an "early evening snack". I don't think it should be considered as afternoon tea or snack, barely on the fact, it is too late to call it afternoon! However, I will add that the"merienda" as such can be something sweet or savoury.

[image]

Comment: Claridges serves 'late afternoon tea' up to 5:30, so if the OP's time is correct then it's not too late to be a 'late afternoon' tea  https://www.claridges.co.uk/restaurants-bars/afternoon-tea/

Comment: Would you mind translating that spanish caption on your picture?

Comment: uhhh what are we looking at

Comment: @Wilson the translation would be "We are already packing the hams you will receive this Christmas. They will arrive soon"

Comment: Spaniards seem to eat late because their clocks are wrong: lunch slightly after 2 p.m. and dinner after 9 p.m. is not so unreasonable when solar noon in Madrid is after 1 p.m. in winter and 2 p.m. in summer

Comment: I don't think the image adds anything to your answer, and in fact has the potential to add confusion: are you suggesting that the tiny piece of ham would constitute (on its own) a *merienda*? That would indeed be a mere snack rather than a small meal.

Answer (score 1):

There are small meals between lunch and dinner, these are called "Dunch" which is a combination of Lunch and Dinner. (It can also be called "Linner")

If you eat a meal between breakfast and lunch it is called brunch, which is more well known.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dunch
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/submission/545/linner

Comment: IME brunch is eaten instead of breakfast and lunch rather than between them.

Comment: Sometimes, but with these terms I picture them as "social" events more than eating habits. Some people having already eating breakfast, may eat brunch to catch up with their friends or relatives.

Comment: Fair point!  In any case, the most important part of brunch is the mimosas or bloody maries.